# Can't reach EC2 on certain ports

Tags: networking, firewall, amazon-ec2

I'm able to connect to my EC2 with window's putty (port TCP 22) but not other ports (e.g. port TCP 80 or TCP 3000).

Using `netstat` I can see that I'm getting SYN_SENT on ports other than 22:

```
netstat -na |find "35.181.14.57"
  TCP    192.168.53.151:58660   35.181.14.57:22        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.53.151:58694   35.181.14.57:22        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.53.151:62362   35.181.14.57:80        SYN_SENT
  TCP    192.168.53.151:62363   35.181.14.57:80        SYN_SENT
```

The EC2's security group contains the 80 and 3000 ports the same way port 22 is opened. Also, I've tried to completely open the inbound ports:
[image]

Running `curl` locally proves that the server is listening on that port:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:80
Hello World
```

I've also verified that the ubuntu's local firewall is disabled:

```
sudo ufw disable
  Firewall stopped and disabled on system startup
```

Getting crazy over here, what am I missing??

Comment: The IPs in this question were altered for security reasons...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved!
Apparently, it was a bad Hello World example I've downloaded.
It was a node.js server running the following code:

```js
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(3000, "127.0.0.1");
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:3000/');
```

And when specifying an IP, the server listens to requests that are targeted to that IP.
Removing the IP - solved the issue.

```
}).listen(3000);
```